# Can't git fetch through SSH

Tags: git, version-control, ssh

I've setup a git repository one a remote server. Now I'm trying to checkout from it with:

```
git fetch ssh://username@url.com/~username/workfolder/
```

but I get an error:

```
fatal: Not a git repository
```

What am I doing wrong? Could it be the server does not support Git+SSH?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try

```
git clone ssh://username@url.com/~username/workfolder/
```

Which will create the repository on your local machine. Any commits you make to that branch are to your local repository, and when you want to push back up to the remote server you can run:

```
git push ssh://username@url.com/~username/workfolder/
```

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought. So after that, if I do a commit does it just go to my local repository? What about remote? I haven't quite grasped how I should be using Git.

Comment: Yes, it would commit to your local repository, and when you want to send back to the remote you do 'git push [remote]'.

Comment: Or just `git push`, at least in newer versions of git.

Answer (score 4):

`git fetch` fails because it expects to be run from within an existing git repository. As Andy Hume notes, you must first `git clone` to create a local copy of an existing repo.

Further, it defines a [git remote](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-remote.html) called `origin` which is set to the URL that you cloned from.  This is the default remote used when you type `git fetch` or `git pull` to retrieve new commits into your local repository, and the default destination when you `git push` to push your new local commits out to a remote repository.  You do not need to include `ssh://username@url.com/~username/workfolder/` in your push command if that is where you cloned from.

Here are some other useful references, from http://gitready.com/:

- [Pushing and pulling](http://gitready.com/beginner/2009/01/21/pushing-and-pulling.html)
- [Push only to bare repositories](http://gitready.com/advanced/2009/02/01/push-to-only-bare-repositories.html)

Answer (score 0):

Could be the tilde ~ 
Try: ssh://username@url.com/username/workfolder